3 problems come with. How can i deal with it?please tell
I want to get update my ubuntu so i run some code. Then i stuck in ubuntu loop zone
First E: if i want to install any pakage then come error and run "apt --fix-broken install ". When i run it. Then again come another E :
1st is:- E, pkgProblemReasolver:reasolve generated breaks,this may be caused by help package.
2nd is:- E:Unable to correct dependencies.

Your output suggests that you installed some wrong-release package, or some non-Ubuntu package that is incompatible with other packages on your system. Usually one of the last things you successfully installed. Locate and uninstall it.

Ok i will try now

@user535733 : how to locate unusual file and remove it. I new so i don’t know too much. Can you give me this command .I try to locate from seeing YouTube vedio and see the question in ubuntu. But i can't!

There is no single command. Look up how to find and read your apt logs. Or look up how to review your shell command history. Maybe those will refresh your memory.

Fundamentally, what happened is that you somehow told the system that two incompatible things must be true. "I want X installed", and "I want Y installed", but X and Y are incompatible. So apt has tried its best to do what you commanded, and this is the point apt finally hit the edge of the cliff. Apt cannot take you any farther.

If I were troubleshooting your system, I would need the complete output of sudo apt update, the complete output of sudo apt upgrade, the complete apt history.log file, and the complete apt term.log file. They are all easy to obtain. Then, the hard part, is learning how to read each one, line by line. You have two choices: You can take the learning path (slow), or you can reinstall Ubuntu (fast).

You have a dependency from virtualbox 6.1.50-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1 in Ubuntu 20.04 which can't be met for one of two possible reasons 1. There is a conflict with held packages. 2. Some non-default software source that you added to /etc/apt/sources.list is preventing you from installing the virtualbox 6.1.50-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1 package. There is insufficient information in your question to ascertain which of these two possibilities apply. Including the output of cat /etc/apt/sources.list in your question might point to a second duplicate question.

I can't install or ubgrade. Because fix broken install come error. When i run Command : sudo apt --fix-broken install then other 2 error's are come that is : 1/error,pkgproblemResolver ::Resolve generated breaks,this maybe caused by held pakage.2/ Unable to correct dependencies.

Last i run This command update: sudo apt-get update && sudo-get upgrade. Then all problem comes. They told me 1024 mb free from disk, i type yes button. Now when i off laptop again on. Give user name or password. Then come before upgrading you need to install all valuable package. But i can't install from apt --fix-broken Install this error come

@karel : i run :/etc/apt/sources.list then come -bash:/etc/apt/sources.list :permission denied . Then i run second command :cat /etc/apt/sources.list then It's come focal main restricted, N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the ubuntu team, Focal Multiverse, Security maintain restricted, Focal -backports main restricted Universe Multiverse etc

According to the third and last comment your software sources that you listed are default software sources for Ubuntu 20.04, so the "E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages" duplicate question would apply.

How can i fix there all 3 error . Can you tell me step by step please

@karel : check one time my first or second question. You go direct third question. Check this to

The best thing you can do is to copy all the relevant text from the terminal, including the results of  sudo apt --fix-broken install and cat /etc/apt/sources.list and then paste it into your question as plain text. That will minimize unnecessary guesswork.

@karel : How can it be possible. Beacuse i can't go my laptop display. I stuck in terminal. That's why i can't open firefox. How can copy and Paste in question plain text

It's OK because you don't need it. The error message you got is telling you that you pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages. If that doesn't work try solving the unmet dependencies error with How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?.
